# How can I add files created in a build phase as bundle resources?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a number of files with the extension .input that I need to process to create corresponding .output files.  I need those output files to be included in the bundle as resources.

In the target's Build Phases tab I've created a "New Run Script Phase" with the following script:

```sh
for f in ${SRCROOT}/Folder/*.input; do
    some-tool < "$f" > "${f%.input}".output;
done
```

That creates the files I need, but how do I add all of the .output files to the build as bundle resources?  I've tried adding `${SRCROOT}/Folder/*.output` to the Output Files section but it doesn't do anything.

Any help much appreciated!